# SyntaxError: bad input on line 3 cannot find a solution for this problem

Tags: python, syntax-error

Write a program to prompt for a score between 0.0 and 1.0. If the score is out of range, print an error. If the score is between 0.0 and 1.0, print a grade using the following table:
Score Grade
`>= 0.9 A`
`>= 0.8 B`
`>= 0.7 C`
`>= 0.6 D`
`< 0.6 F`
If the user enters a value out of range, print a suitable error message and exit. For the test, enter a score of 0.85.

Here is my solution

`score = input("Enter Score: ")`
`m = float(score)`
`if m >= 0.9`
`print(A)`
`if m >= 0.8`
`print(B)`
`if m >=0.7` 
`print(C)`
`if m >= 0.6`
`print(D)`
`if m<0.6`
`print(F)`
`else:`
`print(Error)`

Comment: You are using `A`, `B`, etc. as if they are variables - but they aren’t. Use `”A”`, `”B”`, etc. instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing colons with your `if` statements. Replace

```
if m >= 0.9
```

with

```
if m >= 0.9:
```

Comment: did and it moved to the next line saying SyntaxError: bad input on line 5

Comment: Well, my comment applies to all if statements